# Fixed inline-block div with negative margin-right and shifting float: what's special about -4px?

Tags: css, html, css-float, margin

This is strange.  I'm trying to have a fixed-width div next to a right-floated div, and I don't want to reorder the divs (because this is distributed theme).  So I'm playing with negative margin-right on the fixed div, and I get what seems to me strange: if it's -4px or less, then the float moves to the side; otherwise, it stays below.

Play with the [live demo with code at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/atubil/2/edit), which has this:

```
<style>
  .container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .one {
    margin-right: -4px; /* If <= -4, .two box shifts up */
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .two {
    float: right;
  }
</style>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box one"></div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
  </div>
```

Can someone explain the mystery? What's special about the number -4 in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`4px` just happens to be the width of a "space" at that `font-size`.

If you change the `font-size` of `#container` to say, `32px`, [it breaks](http://jsbin.com/atubil/3).

Sensible ways to fix this include:

- [Remove `margin-right: -4px` and then remove the whitespace between the `div`s in the HTML](http://jsbin.com/atubil/4).
- Don't use `display: inline-block`. Instead, [`float: left` the left `div`, and `float: right` the right `div`](http://jsbin.com/atubil/6).

  - If you're worried about [it breaking](http://jsbin.com/atubil/7) when you don't have a fixed `height` on the container, then you must clear the floats. Use `overflow: hidden` on the container, or use [clearfix](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/).
  - [With `overflow: hidden`](http://jsbin.com/atubil/8) (use this unless you have [*specific* problems](http://fordinteractive.com/misc/overflow/))
  - [With clearfix](http://jsbin.com/atubil/9)

Comment: Good eye! Would have never caught that, but it makes perfect sense now.
The reason I don't want to use a float on the left is because I want to use a fluid size between min-width and max-width with the div trying to take as much space as possible.  But that's another story, and I'm not sure it's possible yet.